# How to save a shap.DeepExplainer (SwigPyObject) to a file?

Tags: python, pickle, swig, shap

I tried to save my `shap` explainer of type `DeepExplainer` using `pickle.dump`, but I get the error: `can't pickle SwigPyObject objects`. My code:

```
my_shap_explainer = DeepExplainer(my_model, background)
pickle.dump(my_shap_explainer, my_file)
```

```
TypeError: can't pickle SwigPyObject objects
```

What is the best way to store this class to a file?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/dill/ have you tried the dill library? I think it may be able to add the functionality you are looking for